# How can I run code in my top-level activity after returning from a child activity?

Tags: android

My top-level activity displays quotes, and it can launch a child activity that adds quotes. All of that works, but I want to make it so after a quote was added, it will update to that new quote. I have a method `setLatestQuote()` which sets the text with animations (via `TextSwitcher`) and changes the background color with another animation.

I'm not sure how to get the code to run after we've returned from the activity. I've tried with overriding `onActivityResult()` and it seems to run all the code before it actually goes back to the main activity.

I launch the child activity like so:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Quotr.this, AddQuote.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_from_bottom, R.anim.pullback);
```

Then that activity will set its return value depending if the quote was added or if the user cancelled, and this is my `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                View view = findViewById(R.id.touch);
                Snackbar.make(view, "Quote added", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                current = quoteList.size() - 1;
                setLatestQuote();
            }
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But as I mentioned, it seems to run all of this code as the child activity closes, rather than after the parent activity has opened, so the Snackbar doesn't display, and the quotes just teleport into view.

I'm pretty sure `onResume()` launches once the activity is made, but from my understanding, onResume will launch more than just when I return from this child activity, such as after `onCreate()`, and I don't want this code running then. Only after I return from this specific child activity.

Comment: Did you set "setResult(RESULT_OK)" in your AddQuote activity before finish?

Comment: Yes, onActivityResult code is running fine, it just runs too early. I tested it out with a Toast notification and all of it works, it just doesn't work with a Snackbar and for playing my animations since the main activity isn't up yet when the code runs.

Comment: You could use the onActivityResult call to set a flag in your activity and then check the flag in your onResume to run your  animations etc... This way you have control and you are leveraging activity life-cycle.

Comment: I actually gave that a shot earlier but onResume still plays too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky code, you can just delay display time.
It seems that there is some "slow point". You need to find there and fix it.

Or as @Duncan mentioned, you can set boolean flag in onActivity result, and check the flag in onResume to show your Snackbar.

Change

```
 Snackbar.make(view, "Quote added", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

To

```
// In your activity
Handler hander = new Hander();

// Replace to...
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Quote added", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);              
        }
    }, 1000);
```